# Local leader with multiple characters in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to map the leader to Space and then the local leader to Space+l (l is the lowercase L) in Vim 8?

Comment: Did you... try?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `let maplocalleader="  l"` because my leader is defined as " ", also tried "<space>l", these didn't seem to work, but ",l" worked. Also tried "<leader>l".